# Docker compose: command after docker-compose run command

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I follow this tutorial: 
[Python Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) In this tutorial, it will create a docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

After that, running docker compose command for building project:

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
```

The thing I don't know is: as I read another docker tutorial, often we just run `docker-compose run` for running project. What is the meaning of those commands after:  `web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` As I understand, this command means: creating a python project first, and then calling `docker-compose.yml` for configuration. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose run` is used to run a one-time command in a service's container. It cannot be used without arguments - at least service name is required. For more information on that command please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/). The command you mentioned:

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
```

executes `django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` in the `web` container of your project, overriding the default command

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

specified for the `web` service in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Slight clarification, it actually doesn't run the command _in_ the existing container. It creates a new one. If you want to run commands in an existing container, use `docker-compose exec`.